# WCF enums, What if I don't mark members as EnumMember?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, enums

```
[DataContract]
public enum Color
{
    Red,
    Blue
}

[DataContract]
public enum Color1
{
    [EnumMember]
    Red,
    [EnumMember]
    Blue
}
```

will this two enums treated differently when serializing, or at client side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't markn enum value with the EnumMember attribute it will not be part of the data
contract. This means that it won't appear in wsds/contract/proxies and that the client won't be able to use it.

Comment: not written that in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347875(v=vs.110).aspx under the chatper "Simple enumerations" it says if you write nothing then its serializable as if you set the flag to all.

Comment: That is: Opt-in only applies *when* a type is marked with DataContractAttribute.

Answer (score 9):

As you have applied the `DataContractAttribute` to the enum, you must explicitly state which members of that enum should be included, through the use of the `EnumMemberAttribute`.

So in your case, the two enums will produce two different contracts, one with no members, and one with two members, `Red` and `Blue`.

If you do not apply the `DataContractAttribute` to an enum, all members of that enum will implicitly be in the contract.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347875.aspx) for an explanation, primarily the `Enumeration Member Values` and
 `Notes on Simple Enumerations` sections.

Answer (score 0):

It won't necessarily be recognised on the client as a member of the *known type* that is `Color` because you're not explicitly saying it's part of the contract and so there is no reason to respect it when generating the proxy.